# Unintuitive postgresql string sorting behaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have a table **A with column a varchar(2)**. This table is filled with the following rows **('-', '-0', '-1', '0', '00', '01')**.
And we have table **B with column b varchar(2)**. This table is filled with the following rows: **('a', 'ab', 'ac', 'b', 'bb', 'bc')**.
Now if I execute `select * from B order by b asc;` I get what I expect:

```
a
ab
ac
b
bb
bc
```

But if I execute `select * from A order by a asc;` then I end up with something I do not quite expect:

```
-
0
-0
00
01
-1
```

I expected that it would sort rows in the following way:

```
-
-0
-1
0
00
01
```

In the actual result minus is positioned below 0, yet when it is combined with a number 1 it is positioned above 01. Is this behaviour documented somewhere? I am using postgresql 10.15 on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I don't reproduce exactly those results, but they are still inexplicable:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e2d3297d66644a61860faf5e523e5177.

Comment: What is the locale and encoding in the database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Borrowed your fiddle example for answer below to illustrate how to 'correct'.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver . . . I don't see what the locale has to do with it.  The hyphens are not appearing together in the sorted list.

Comment: The locale is used by `initdb` to set the initial settings for sorting among other things: [Locale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html). It is a data point to determine where things started at.

Answer (score 0):

Using fiddle information from  @Gordon Linoff with one change:

```
create table t (x varchar(2) COLLATE "C");

insert into t (x)
    values ('-'), ('-0'), ('-1'), ('0'), ('00'), ('01');

select *
from t
order by x
;
 x  
----
 -
 -0
 -1
 0
 00
 01
(6 rows)
```

So it is down to collation type. For more information see [Collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html).

To further illustrate:

```
alter table t add column y varchar(2) COLLATE "en_US"; 

insert into t (y)
    values ('-'), ('-0'), ('-1'), ('0'), ('00'), ('01');

select *
from t
order by x,y
;
  x   |  y   
------+------
 -    | NULL
 -0   | NULL
 -1   | NULL
 0    | NULL
 00   | NULL
 01   | NULL
 NULL | -
 NULL | 0
 NULL | -0
 NULL | 00
 NULL | 01
 NULL | -1
(12 rows)
```